# How to make two side by side maps match up in layout view in MapInfo?

Tags: mapinfo, comparison

I am working with two maps that have different thematic elements on each- in this case, I made two different columns to display the concentration of chemical found on that location. I display the current standards (2-20, 20-70 and >70) in X, Y, and Z colors in one map, then the other map has the proposed standards which are stricter (environmental regulation goals) as 2-4, 4-10, and >10 as the same colors in the first range. The lowest range is X color, middle range is Y color, and highest range is Z color. I want to make the map images match up exactly, so that people can compare side by side, same scale, same everything, so I can present the differences between the two.

**How do I make the two map images match exactly?**

I am very inexperienced in MapInfo, my only experience has been mapping and cleaning up data in the tables. I only just started playing with the layout tab about 4 business days ago. I will need a bit more guidance than "just try this", I will have to do a lot of additional research and googling and trial and error to find a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When one of the map windows is active, the "Change View" menu item in the "Map" menu (or in the map window's context menu) allows you to change the position and scale exactly:

[image: MapInfo Change View]

These three numbers describe the same thing. Just ensure that both layout frames have the same width.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the Sync Windows tool to make the window stay synced.

When you zoom or pan in one map, the other maps will zoom and pan to the same position.

[image]